# Finding the Fourier transform of tf''(t)

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to find the fourier transform of $t\cdot f''$. The rules I've found that relates to this seems to be that for a function $f(t)$ and it's Fourier transform $F(\omega)$ the following holds:
$\frac{d^nf(t)}{dt^n} = (i\omega)^nF(\omega)$
and
$(-it)^nf(t) = \frac{d^nF(\omega)}{d\omega^n}$.

Does this mean that the Fourier transform is
$(i\cdot t)^2 \cdot \frac{dF(t)}{d\omega}$?

Comment: Isn't the value of $\frac{dF(t)}{d\omega}$ zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform is
$$
i\frac{d}{d\omega}\bigl((i\,\omega)^2F(\omega)\bigr).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since I'm slightly retarded, how do you reach that conclusion?

Comment: Let $g(t)=f''(t)$ and let $G(\omega)$ be the Fourier transform of $g$. Then, according to the rules in your post, the Fourier transform of $t\,g=i(-i\,t)g$ is  $i\,\frac{d}{d\omega}G(\omega)$. Now, again according to the same rules, the Fourier transform of $G$ is $(i\,\omega)^2F(\omega)$.